# Sylius+FOS+PUGX Multi User: Overriding User Model

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, sylius

Sylius with FOS and PUGX MultiUser Bundle that allows registering of 3 different users via 3 different forms, with 3 different roles, etc. Since Sylius User is defined as:

> > ->Sylius\Component\Core\Model\User.php

```
namespace Sylius\Component\Core\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\AddressInterface;

class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface{
...
}
```

Since userOne and userTwo are supposed to extend an abstract class, as per PUGX multiuser Bundle docs, we have:

> > ->Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User.php

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_user_pugx")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"userone" = "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\userOne", "userTwo" = "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\userTwo", "userThree" = "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Admin"})
 *
 */
abstract class User extends BaseUser {...}
```

So now we only need, our REAL final classes:

> > ->Acme\UserBundle\Entity\userOne.php

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Mod\UserBundle\Entity\User as User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userOne")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class userOne extends User {..}
```

So we are extending this way: userOne extends 'Abstract User' extends 'Sylius User' extends 'FOS User'.

But I can't update my schema:  The table with name 'bbdd.sylius_user_address' already exists

What am I doing wrong? Isn't it the logical way the user classes should extend each other?

Comment: Am I the only one trying to extend Sylius Model in the world with PUGX Bundle?? Nobody else has faced this?

Comment: Hi, I think i'm facing the same problem as you did. My users where working fine, but since I've installed some bundles of the sylius packages, the discriminator map for one of my class doesn't exists anymore. Did you found a solution ?

Comment: Yes I did. I had to update config.yml to register pugx_user_manager as this Bundle informs and also modify the User Model inside sylius/CoreBundle to your User Entity. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you need to use PUX as Sylius doesn't use FOSUSerBundle anymore.