# Sylius installing cart/orderBundle - service "sylius.translatable.listener" error

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to install only the cartBundle and orderBundle (with their dependencies) for my application. I'm still a newbie in sf2 so stop me if I'm wrong in my thinking.
So on packagist I found the lastest version :

```
"sylius/order-bundle": "0.14.*@dev"
```

But composer wouldn't install all the dependencies by itself (all the *@dev), so I had to manually add all of them to composer.json

After some time I finally got to the configuration of the bundles in **app/config.yml**  and I added the bundles on top of **appKernel.php**.

But then I have this error :

```
ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 106: The service "sylius.translatable.listener" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "sylius.translation.mapping". Did you mean this: "sylius.translation.default.mapping"?
```

I can't figure out what to do know. I probably missed something. I couldn't find the documentation for the translationBundle : http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusTranslationBundle/index.html

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just for curiosity:

i tried to use the

```
"sylius/taxonomy-bundle": "~0.13"
```

in my project and needed to manualy additonaly require

```
"sylius/translation-bundle": "~0.13",
"sylius/locale-bundle": "~0.13",
```

in symfony i also needed to add the bundles to the kernel:

```
new Sylius\Bundle\TaxonomyBundle\SyliusTaxonomyBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\TranslationBundle\SyliusTranslationBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\LocaleBundle\SyliusLocaleBundle(),
```

and

```
#app/config/config.yml
sylius_taxonomy:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        taxonomy: ~
        taxonomy_translation: ~
        taxon: ~
        taxon_translation: ~
sylius_locale:
    driver: doctrine/orm
```

and

```
#app/config/parameters.yml
sylius.translation.default.mapping:
    translatable:
        field: translations
        currentLocale: currentLocale
        fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale
    translation:
        field: translatable
        locale: locale

sylius.locale: %locale%
    sylius.context.locale: %locale%
```

maybe this will shorten the process for someone else..

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml#L239-L247.

I gues you should have similar section in your config.

Comment: I got it one step further by changing the parameter from %sylius.translation.mapping% to %sylius.translation.default.mapping%. But my app is still running errors, probably not directly linked to the translation bundle, but related to that subject (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538916/syliusfospugx-multi-user-overriding-user-model). I'm looking into changing %sylius.model.user.class% (but don't have the bundle to handle the config from your link)